# Как исполнять функции, в зависимости от того, в каком порядке указаны аргументы?

Tags: perl

Например, в скрипте имеется 3 функции:

- sub foo();
- sub bar();
- sub baz();

Имеется также 3 аргумента:

- -ng
- -tc
- -qx

Если пользователь ввёл

```
./script -ng -tc -qx
```

функции должны исполняться в порядке *foo* -> *bar* -> *baz*

Если пользователь ввёл

```
./script -qx -ng -tc
```

то *baz* -> *foo* -> *bar*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массив @ARGV содержит параметры командной строки. Прочитайте его и вызовите функции как нужно. Если других параметров не предполагается, можно перевести в строку для простоты:

```
my $params = join '', @ARGV;

if( $params eq '-ng-tc-qx' ){
  foo();
  bar();
  baz();
}
elsif( $params eq '-qx-ng-tc' ){
  baz();
  foo();
  bar();
}
```

Comment: Мне еще порекомендовали вариант с хэшем, где ключ - аргумент, значение - sub.

Comment: Можно и так конечно. Даже более гибко будет. Тут уж смотрите по своим требованиям.